# How to get every String from an ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I'd like to get a string from my ArrayList, but it contains lines from my input fole. How do I split them correctly to have all the elements?

My program looks like this:

```
private static ArrayList<String> lista;

static void fileReading() {
    inp = new LineNumberReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileNev), "ISO8859-1")));

    String sor;
    while ((sor = inp.readLine()) != null) {

    lista.add(sor);
    lista.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));   
}
```

In another method how do I get this lists only one string and not the line?

EDIT:

Vineet Verma your code is great, but it gets me a great string, and I need to know the indexes of the strings within this,  replace them later, and I can't get it done with only one string.

It's still not working, if I use this:

> ```
>     String[] temp=null;
> for(String s : lista) {
>    temp = s.split("\\W+"); 
> }
> ```
>
> System.out.println(temp);

I get: [Ljava.lang.String;@6ef53890

Wihtin the for I get many : [Ljava.lang.String;@6ef53890

If I use this:

> ```
>    String str ="" ;
>     for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){
>      str+=lista.get(i)+" ";
>
>   String[] temp = new String[str.length()];
>   for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
>        temp[i]=str.valueOf(i);
>        System.out.println(temp[i]);         
>   }
> ```

I get only numbers, and can't figure out how to get the string from str.

Comment: What is an "element" of a line?

Comment: the line is a string...i don't understand the question.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through each line word by word?

Comment: your requirement is not clear.; what is it that you want???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your problem:

in the other method

```
public String convertToString(ArrayList<String> al)
{
String str ="" ;
for(int i=0; i<al.size;i++){str+=al.get(i)+" ";}
return str;
}
```

If i understand your query correctly then this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **splitting at word boundaries**. You can use the below sample code for simple cases (This is just a sample and might not be accurate. Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) for more specific regex that meets your needs).

```
String [] words = line.split("\\W+");
```

NOTE: Word boundaries are language specific and requires you to use i18n libraries if you really require i18n-safe split.

Search for "splitting at word boundaries"in google.

Comment: For example the file starts: "package asd;"
I need the Strings "package" and "asd"; and not the whole line.
Thank you for the tutorial, I know about split() method, but I can't get to use it properly, it won't work. 
Does anyone have a code for this?

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question, since it's still not working